# React Native Flatlist Animated View Scrolling Problem

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I tried to "change" the default refresh indicator of a Flatlist in React Native. I thought about to have something like Snapchat or Instagram or the default IOS refresh indicator instead of the ugly Android indicator. Now I tried following:

```js
const screenHeight = Dimensions.get("screen").height;
const lockWidth = screenHeight;
const finalPosition = lockWidth;

const pan = useRef(new Animated.ValueXY({x: 0, y: 0})).current;
  const translateBtn = pan.y.interpolate({
    inputRange: [0, finalPosition / 0.75],
    outputRange: [0, finalPosition / 2],
    extrapolate: 'clamp',
  });
  const panResponder = useRef(
    PanResponder.create({
      onMoveShouldSetPanResponder: () => true,
      onPanResponderGrant: () => {},
      onPanResponderMove: Animated.event([null, {dy: pan.y}], {
        useNativeDriver: false,
      }),
      onPanResponderRelease: (e, g) => {
        if (g.vy > 2 || g.dy > lockWidth / 2) {
          unlock();
        } else {
          reset();
        }
      },
      onPanResponderTerminate: () => reset(),
    }),
  ).current;
  const reset = () => {
    setGeneralState(prevState => ({...prevState, scroll: true}))
    Animated.spring(pan, {
      toValue: {x: 0, y: 0},
      useNativeDriver: true,
      bounciness: 0,
    }).start();
  };
  const unlock = () => {
    setLoading(true)
    Animated.spring(pan, {
      toValue: {x: 0, y: 280},
      useNativeDriver: true,
      bounciness: 0,
    }).start();
    // alert("")
    setTimeout(() => {
      reset();
      setLoading(false)
    }, 1000)
  };
```

It works just as I expect:

[image]

Now the problem:
When the Flatlist is so big that it can be scrolled (if there are many items) I cannot pull down to refresh anymore because React Native always tries to move the flatlist when I'm scrolling.

The FlatList:

```js
<Animated.View
        style={[
          styles.receiverBox,
          {transform: [{translateY: translateBtn}]},
        ]}
        {...panResponder.panHandlers}>
          <View>
            <FlatList
              data={["user1", "user2", "user3", "user4", "user5",]}
              renderItem={({item}) => {
                return(
                  <View style={{backgroundColor: colors.background, padding: 20, marginTop: -5, width: "100%",}}>
                    <Text style={{fontSize: Title1, color: colors.text, textAlign: "center",}}>{item}</Text>
                  </View>
                )
              }}
            />
          </View>
      </Animated.View>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out that this may be a problem from react native or the combination of the flatlist with the pan responder.